# Remove first character from string if 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to remove the first character from my `UITextfield` if it's a 0.

Unfortunately I don't know how to extract the value of the first character or extract the characters of the string after the first character.

Thanks

Comment: i'm not too understand with your question, would you please make it easier to understand?

Comment: Well, extract the text, then look at the first character.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 77, accepted):

One solution could be:

```
if ([string hasPrefix:@"0"] && [string length] > 1) {
    string = [string substringFromIndex:1];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You would probably want something like this, using [hasPrefix:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasPrefix%3a)

```
if ([string hasPrefix:@"0"]) {
    string = [string substringFromIndex:1];
}
```

You could also use [characterAtIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex%3a) which returns a unichar:

```
if ([string characterAtIndex:0] == '0') {
     string = [string substringFromIndex:1];
}
```

Note that, 'a' is character, "a" is C string and @"a" is NSString. They all are different types.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3.0:

```
var myString = "Hello, World"
myString.remove(at: myString.startIndex)

myString // "ello, World"
```

Comment: If this string is dynamic, might want to check if the count is greater than 1: if (string.characters.count > 1) {  }

Comment: ` if it's a 0.`

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

hasPrefix("0") check if the first character is 0 in txtField
and remove it

```
if (self.txtField.text?.hasPrefix("0"))! {         
    self.txtField.text?.remove(at(self.txtField.text?.startIndex)!)
}
```

Comment: remove return a character,

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 5.0**
you can use the following sequence function to check whether string starts with "0" or not

```
if search.starts(with: "0") {                                            
        search.remove(at: search.startIndex)                                      
        print("After Trim search is",search)                                                   
} else {                                                                 
        print("First char is not 0")                                                           
}
```

> Replace the string variable with your current variable name.
> I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

While loop to keep removing first character as long as it is zero

```
while (self.ammountTextField.text?.hasPrefix("0"))! {     
   self.ammountTextField.text?.remove(at: (self.ammountTextField.text?.startIndex)!)
}
```