# Remove leading zero before decimal in a float

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to remove the leading zero on a two decimal place float in xcode.

```
arrFraction = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (float fraction = .00; fraction <=.99; fraction+= .01) {
    NSString *fractionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%", fraction];
    [arrFraction addObject:fractionString];
}
```

This results in a NSMutableArray with values of `0.00` though `0.99`

What I would like is `.00` through `.99`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove first character from string if 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031603/remove-first-character-from-string-if-0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - how to hide leading zero in printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595738/c-how-to-hide-leading-zero-in-printf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this,

```
    NSString *str =@"0000.00013200";
    NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"^0*" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
    str= [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

O/P:-`.00013200`