# Prevent "0" first character on phone pad textfield in swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

How to prevent the "0" for first character, for example if phone number starts with 012345678 then it should prevent to type "0" at first. Below is the swift code

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController {   
var isShowFilter = false
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPhone: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnLogin: ThemeButton!
    func validateView() -> Bool{
       if (self.txtPhone.text?.isEmpty)!{
            GFunctions.ShowAlert(message: StringIdentifier.EnterPhone.rawValue)
            return false
        }
       else if ((self.txtPhone.text?.starts(with: "0")) != nil){
        GFunctions.ShowAlert(message: StringIdentifier.NoEnterZero.rawValue) //Here want to show toast message if user put 0 at first
        return false
       }
       else if (self.txtPassword.text?.isEmpty)!{
            GFunctions.ShowAlert(message: StringIdentifier.EnterPassword.rawValue)
            return false
       }else if (self.txtPassword.text?.count)! < 6 {
            GFunctions.ShowAlert(message: StringIdentifier.ValidPassword.rawValue)
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }   
    @IBAction func btnLoginTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if validateView(){
            isShowFilter = true
            self.APICallLogin()
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

enum StringIdentifier : String{
case NoEnterZero                   = "Do not start with 0"
}
```

Comment: Register to the relevant UITextfile delegate method and try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031603/remove-first-character-from-string-if-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply implement TextField delegate

```
extension LoginVC: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if range.location == 0 && string == "0" {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Make sure, you set `YourViewController` as TextField delegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     txtPhone.delegate = self
}
```